# PHP DOM Parser : find text of all links and change it

Tags: php, string, parsing, dom

I'm new into PHO DOM Parser. I have a string like this :

```
$coded_string = "Hello, my name is <a href="link1">Marco</a> and I'd like to <strong>change</strong> all <a href="link2">links</a> with a custom text";
```

and I'd like to change all text in the links (in the example, *Marco* and *links*) with a custom string, let say *hello*.

How can I do it on PHP? At the moment I only initilized the XDOM/XPATH parser as :

```
$dom_document = new DOMDocument();      
$dom_document->loadHTML($coded_string);
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom_document);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a good sense for xpath here, the following example shows how to select all textnode children ([`DOMText`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php)) of the `<a>` elements and change their text:

```
$dom_document = new DOMDocument();      
$dom_document->loadHTML($coded_string);
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom_document);

$texts = $dom_xpath->query('//a/child::text()');
foreach ($texts as $text)
{
    $text->data = 'hello';
}
```

Let me know if this is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try phpQuery ( http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ ):

```
<?php

    $coded_string = 'Hello, my name is <a href="link1">Marco</a> and I\'d like to <strong>change</strong> all <a href="link2">links</a> with a custom text';

    require('phpQuery.php');

    $doc = phpQuery::newDocument($coded_string);
    $doc['a']->html('hello');
    print $doc;

?>
```

Prints:

```
Hello, my name is <a href="link1">hello</a> and I'd like to <strong>change</strong> all <a href="link2">hello</a> with a custom text
```

Comment: No Thanks, I'd like to use `DOMDocument` and `DOMXpath`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$coded_string = "Hello, my name is <a href='link1'>Marco</a> and I'd like to <strong>change</strong> all <a href='link2'>links</a> with a custom text";

$dom_document = new DOMDocument();      
$dom_document->loadHTML($coded_string);
$dom_xpath = new DOMXpath($dom_document);

$links = $dom_xpath->query('//a');
foreach ($links as $link)
{
    $anchorText[] = $link->nodeValue;
}

$newCodedString = str_replace($anchorText, 'hello', $coded_string);

echo $newCodedString;
```

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like to change the value, not store it in an array :)

Comment: You should be able to get what you want from there, nevertheless I've edited my answer to your preference. Sorry about that.