# Capitalize first letter in <em>

Tags: php, replace, capitalize, ucfirst

```
$item = 'some <html> goes <div class="here"> and </div> can be placed <em>     some words</em>, and then more </html> can exist';
```

**How do I capitalize the first letter of the first word inside `<em>...</em>` only?**

Comment: first letter of the first word

Comment: You do it like you do it with any other string, but this time only on strings within `<em>`.

Comment: I'd use something like SimpleXML to decode the html (wrap it with a dummy root tag first, so it becomes a valid XML doc) and then getting the string in the <em> is trivial - you can walk through the document and then get/set a string if it is a child of an `<em>` element.

Comment: Use a HTML parser, not a regex or an XML parser for it.

Comment: @hakre, I'm not sure how to catch the code inside <em>

Comment: Here is an example for `<a>`, I guess you're clever enough that you know what you need to change for `<em>`: [PHP DOM Parser : find text of all links and change it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019581/php-dom-parser-find-text-of-all-links-and-change-it/8019955#8019955) and you find the [`ucfirst` function here](http://php.net/ucfirst).

Comment: I'm not sure about php dom parser too, its a strange approach to include extra library for a simple uppercase of the letter..

Comment: @Steve: Two libraries to be correct: The PHP string library for `ucfirst` and then the PHP DOMDocument library. But both ship with PHP, so I don't see any problem here. You probably stand more in your own way than anything else.

Comment: Also that DOM Parser comes with proper HTML whitespace normalization which is something you need, too. Probably you're just not aware that your problem is not as simple as it looks on first sight? There is a reason why such DOM Parsers exists even you think they are huge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this?

```
function ucfirstword($str) {
   $estr = explode(" ",$str);
   $estr[0] = ucfirst($estr[0]);
   return implode(" ",$estr);
}

...
echo "<em>     ".ucfirstword("some words")."</em>";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), like this:

```
function replaceStuff($matches){
        return $matches[1].strtoupper($matches[2]);
}

$item=preg_replace_callback("/(<em[^>]*>[^\\w]*)(\\w)/i","replaceStuff",$item);
```

↪ [Read more about using preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

Note: you can also do this using CSS; to do this, you can use this code:

```
em:first-letter {
 text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

↪  [Read more about the text-transform property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-transform).

Comment: -1: this will uppercase the `<em>` tag as well, what an inprecise "I throw some code on it until it works" suggestion.

Comment: Another edit: any characters before the first word are now optional

Answer (score -1):

if you need only this string, you can do like this

```
 $item = 'some <html> goes <div class="here"> and </div> can be placed <em>     ';
 $item .= ucfirst("some words");
 $item .= '</em>, and then more </html> can exist';
echo $item;
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
$item = 'some <html> goes <div class="here"> and </div> can be placed <em style="text-transform: uppercase">some</em>, and then more </html> can exist';
```

Maybe this helps you.